# How do you export the installed program report after Easy Transfer?

Tags: windows, migration

I used the Easy Transfer Agent to export items from a old computer.  Used it again to import items onto the new computer.  Everything worked as expected.

After the Easy Transfer Agent completes it gives you a list of what is on the old computer as far as programs are concerned and includes what is already on the computer.  As of now, I can only screenshot the old applications, but I can't find a way to save the list in any kind of persistent storage.

How to I export the list?  The only toggle I can find on the form is the report selection.

Comment: If there isn't an option displayed to generate a list, my logical guess is that, the option does not exist.

Comment: My hopes are that there is another method possibly to bring the interface up or possibly a log file that can be looked through.  I just know that it appears after transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but - Look in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Easy Transfer\PostMigData", there is a folder named as the date the that the transfer happened, and there are a couple of HTML files in there that hold the contents of the report.